# Volley Error for new Request Queue

Tags: java, android, rest, api, android-volley

When I have applied a simple code of using valley library,I have used google example "https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple"

```
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            String url ="http://www.google.com";

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                            message.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    message.setText("That didn't work!");
                }
            });
                // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                     queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I get that below error.

> E/Volley: [77336] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int java.lang.String.offset' on a null object reference
>                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int java.lang.String.offset' on a null object reference
>                                                                           at java.lang.String.compareToIgnoreCase(String.java:560)
>                                                                           at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:77)
>                                                                           at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:66)
>                                                                           at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java:277)
>                                                                           at java.util.TreeMap.putInternal(TreeMap.java:240)
>                                                                           at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:186)
>                                                                           at com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.toHeaderMap(NetworkResponse.java:138)
>                                                                           at com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.(NetworkResponse.java:0)
>                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:169)
>                                                                           at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:113)

Comment: can you please tell me which line has the error(Logcat Pointing line)?

Comment: Actually I don't know what do you mean by Pointing line, that's the error appear when I'm applying the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I after a lot of work I found the solution, I was using a volley library from Github instead of using "compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'" in  dependencies of app file. Hope if anyone can explain it more why I couldn't use library from Github. thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1):

The code says you have encountered a `NullPointer exception`

> That means the variables you are using in this code is null at
>   runtime.
>
> check your passing values which is not null.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35958704/5962715)

Comment: I'm not using a variables containing data, I'm trying to test that simple request!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the substring from response that is:-

```
message.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
```

after change:

```
   if(response.lemght>500){
        message.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
   }else{

        message.setText("Response is: "+ response);
   }
```

try this
while creating the RequestQueue please pass the context not the getApplicationContext():-

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);//if you are in activity, if you are in fragment then **getActivity()**
```

Comment: Still have the same error after applying your change.

Comment: sometimes the getApplicationContext may return null so try to change it to this or getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

While you make a network call you might get success but not data sometimes..So make sure you make a null check before accessing data.

```
if(response!=null){
  message.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
}
```

Comment: Still the same, it seems the error not from the "response".

Comment: Ya thats what I said.I solved your null pointer issue..But your not getting response data and your are trying to set it.Thats why app was crashing

Comment: Your are hitting "http://www.google.com" and expecting string response?How bro..try to hit different api which gives you String response or json response and try.Or if possible check retrofit library.Its same as volley but is new one

Comment: I have applied my own json response from the server but still have the same issue, and that example is provided my google!

Comment: Use Json gRequest instead of StringRequest then

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I have applied, Json response for post request but still have the same error, do you think i may have a problem on Volley library?

Comment: Why I'm still getting that error after applying if statement as you mention.